# varnish 4.0.1 segfaults for unknown reason

Tags: segmentation-fault, varnish, child-process

Yeseterday we experienced our first segfault with varnish. We ran varnish varnish-3.0.2 without any problems for a year+.

Now we have updated to varnish-4.0.1 and got this error:

```
Oct  5 18:42:03 xxxxxxxx kernel: [2123420.982139] varnishd[11453]: segfault at 40 ip 0000000000417a30 sp 00007f79c
d114190 error 4 in varnishd[400000+88000]
Oct  5 18:43:05 xxxxxxxx varnishd[10236]: Child (10240) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Oct  5 18:43:06 xxxxxxxx varnishd[10236]: Child (10240) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Oct  5 18:43:07 xxxxxxxx varnishd[10236]: Child (10240) died signal=11 (core dumped)
Oct  5 18:43:07xxxxxxxx varnishd[10236]: Child cleanup complete
Oct  5 18:43:07 xxxxxxxx varnishd[10236]: child (24567) Started
Oct  5 18:43:07 xxxxxxxx varnishd[10236]: Child (24567) said Child starts
```

We have read that people experience problems when using var vmod but we dont, and we still get this error.

Heres the config:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
-T localhost:6082 \
-p thread_pool_add_delay=2 \
-p thread_pools=6 \
-p thread_pool_min=200 \
-p thread_pool_max=5000 \
-p thread_pool_add_delay=2 \
-f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
-S /etc/varnish/secret \
-s malloc,25G"
```

Correction; We got this error in our logs:

```
Oct  5 18:42:03 xxx xxx xxx kernel: [2123420.982139] varnishd[11453]:      segfault at 40 ip 0000000000417a30 sp 00007f79cd114190 error 4 in varnishd[400000+88000]
Oct  5 18:43:05 xxx xxx xxx varnishd[10236]: Child (10240) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Oct  5 18:43:06 xxx xxx xxx varnishd[10236]: Child (10240) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Oct  5 18:43:07 xxx xxx xxx varnishd[10236]: Child (10240) died signal=11 (core dumped)
Oct  5 18:43:07 xxx xxx xxx varnishd[10236]: Child cleanup complete
Oct  5 18:43:07 xxx xxx xxx varnishd[10236]: child (24567) Started
Oct  5 18:43:07 xxx xxx xxx varnishd[10236]: Child (24567) said Child starts
Oct  5 18:43:27 xxx xxx xxx kernel: [2123504.480962] hrtimer: interrupt took 219959 ns
```

Somebody gots a clue why this problem is occuring?

Best regards!
/Daniel

Comment: Did you upgrade the VCL syntax for V4? Is there any inline C in your VCL? Is this running on an OpenVZ container? Apart from those, hard to say.:-)

Comment: Yes we did. No we do not use any inline C, neither any vmods (accept the std lib). No but we run the server on VMware and our operating system is ubuntu 12.04. Yeah this problem is weird!

Talked to some guy on varnish irc, and he recommended upgrading to varnish 4.0.2 but havent have time to do that yet...

Comment: Was this from source? If it was, did you update build-essential and anything else needed to compile the code? Sorry for the obvious questions - Varnish is notoriously stable! :-)

Comment: Not we didnt compile it from source. Haha thats alright, thank you for asking anyhow!! :-)

Yeah i agree, it is so stable so this problem was a really surprise for me!

Comment: OK, well I am stumped. You may have a long night ahead source debugging. ;-)